# CSS Have elements in left, right and centre

Tags: css

I am trying to align elements so that they are left, right and centre this works however there is a gap below each element (see: http://seananderson.co.uk/) and I want them to be side by side with no gap below, here is my CSS:

```
#introduction {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
}
#ibiza {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-right: 33%;
    width: 33%;
}
#social {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `float`, `float` 'em all!(and _`clear`_ `#twitter`)

Comment: You should really study up on how [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), and [block formatting contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) all work together.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ibiza styles to this one.

`#ibiza {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 33%
    }`

Comment: All of your styles need tweaking but this small style change to #ibiza will fix your issue

Comment: @user228908 accept this as an answer, I can see, You have used it in your site and helped you. Thank you.